# How to use -exec option with 'find'

Tags: sed, files, find

Im trying to use -exec to invoke a sed statement below:

`find '$path' -mtime +$daysold -exec sed -E -f redact.sed file.txt {} \;`.
what does `{}` do? and what goes inside `{}`?

Comment: As the fine manual tells you, `find` will put the found filename where it sees `{}`. Not clear if you want the `file.txt` in your command but it is not definitely wrong.

Answer (score -2):

it should be `find "$path" -mtime +$daysold -exec sed -E -f redact.sed file.txt \;`

and put `$path` in `" "` instead of the `' '`, also remove the braces

Comment: This will execute `sed -E -f redact.sed` on the same `file.txt` once for each matching file found - while syntactically valid, it's hard to see a practical reason to do that