# Execute sed on all file under a directory

Tags: sed, files, find

I use `find` to get the path to my directory and I want to use `sed` to redact ALL the files under the directory that have been modified more than `n days`

I run this:
`find "$path" -type f -mtime +$days -exec sed -i.bak -E -f redact.sed {} \;`.

`$path`: path to current directory.
`$days` number of days since lost modified.

What is wrong with this? More specifically, I don't know what to put after `redact.sed` to get it to run all files under the directory.

Comment: Didn't you just ask https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/611891/how-to-use-exec-option-with-find which was closed as a duplicate? What isn't working? What is in the redact.sed script?

Comment: @icarus this is asking how to use find to run all files in a directory, the link you're talking about is asking how to use -exec command with sed. so no, completely different question

Comment: the redact.sed just takes a number and replaces it with %, but I want to do it for all files under directory  specify in $path

Comment: This may be executing `sed -i.bak -E -f redact.sed redact.sed` - running the sed script on itself could be a problem.

Comment: why did you write `redact.sed` twice?

Comment: What are the values of `$path` and `$days`? Btw, `$path` is an unfortunate name for a variable, as it can be easily confused with `$PATH`.

Comment: It's amazing how similar this (the above) is to [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/611928/80216). Is this homework?

Comment: assume `$days` is 2 and `$path` to be user/file/redact