# execute all files under a directory

Tags: sed, files, find, directory

Im trying to use `find` to execute all the files under a directory. I have a sed script that will replace all `#` with `//`.
assume my directory is `/path/to/directory` and it contains `file1 file2 file3`

using `find` and `sed`: `find /path/to/directory -type f -exec sed -f file.sed {} \;`.

how do I make it to where it runs ALL files (`file1 file2 file3)` under the `path/to/directory` directory?

Comment: What is the error you are getting? Merely saying its not working is very unhelpful.

Comment: it says no directory or file found

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Execute sed on all file under a directory](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/611930/execute-sed-on-all-file-under-a-directory)

Comment: `-exec` is executed from the starting directory, while `-execdir` is used to execute commands in the directory where the matching file is found. See `man find`. Or do you want a third directory to be specified?

Comment: Are the files that you are `find`ing, executable-files / programs?